# Is ip restrict a safe way to go?

Tags: php

Is it safe to use this code to allow permission to access site?

```
if(!$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"){
```

?

Is it possible to get user Mac address ?

Comment: If you're going to do this, use firewall rules rather than application logic.

Comment: Sort of depends on *how* secure it needs to be... an IPv4 address can represent an entire network rather than a single user - so it depends on what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Well whats safe? If you do this, you may be able to access your site. But then again, if you do not have a static ip, it wont work for long.

A better solution with php would be to just write a simple login, with non-hardcoded user and pass.

If you run an apache, you could use .htaccess for this too, just set a password and anybody wanting to access your site (if thats what you specify), is required to first type the user/pass combination.